# Does `appsync` support `withFilter` in subscription?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-appsync

I have a graphql written in nodejs with `Apollo Server`. Below is the `subscription` code. As you can see that it uses `withFilter` which takes two function parameters.

In the first function, it takes the arguments and call `pubSub.subscribe('TRANSACTION_REQUEST' + args.transactionId)` to subscribe to a topic. Note that the topic name is a dynamic one which includes the transaction ID from the user request.

In the second function, it filter out unmatched userId.

So my question is how can I implement these two functions in `Appsync`.

```
const resolvers = {
...
  Subscription: {
    requestTransaction: {
      subscribe: withFilter(
        (rootValue: any, args: any, context: any, info: any) => {
          console.log('req txn with filter args', args);
          return pubSub.subscribe('TRANSACTION_REQUEST' + args.transactionId)(
            rootValue,
            args,
            context,
            info,
          );
        },
        (transactionResponse: any, transactionRequest: any) => {
          console.log('with filter transaction');
          console.log('subscribe:', transactionResponse, transactionRequest);
          return (
            transactionResponse.userId ===
            transactionRequest.transactionInput.userId
          );
        },
      ),
    },
  },
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AppSync you won't be able to log as you incrementally filter the subscription events, but you can have the user supply the attributes to filter by so that the resulting subscription events are the same.

Here `Event` is just the type of the object that your mutation returns:

```
type Subscription {
    subscribeTransaction(topic: String userId: String): Event
            @aws_subscribe(mutations: ["fooMutation"])
}
```

to start a subscription:

```
subscription onTransact {
    subscribeTransaction(topic: "TRANSACTION_REQUEST" + args.transactionId userId: args.userId){
        id
        foo
        bar
    }
}
```

Note:

- the name `onTransact` is arbitrary
- assumes `transactionId` and `userId` were passed inside `args`
- `id`, `foo` and `bar` will only be returned if the mutation also requested these attributes